# How to pick last elements in a getter in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an action to get all my favourites posts. But for one of my components I need to show only the last five ones, not all of them. I started to write a getter for this but I am struggling to find a solution. What method I can use here (where the question marks are)?

```
getLimitFavorites(state) {
  return function(limit) {
    return state.favorites. ? ? ?
  }
},
```

Comment: Is it really your intention to return a function?

Comment: I was told to use this. Also can we apply .pick method for this?

Comment: So my getter must address to the state called Favorites and return the function which would give us last 5 posts in Favorites

Comment: By returning a function from the getter, it means that you will need to call it like a function rather than like a property as you typically would with Vuex. It also means that you will lose the caching of a typical computed property in Vue. The only thing you gain is that you can call it with different limits. You've not, however, mentioned that you want different limits, just the last 5, so you would not typically return a function in this case and would simply `return state.favorites.slice(-5)` from the `getLimitFavorites` function.

Comment: Okay, I see now. Thanks for this thorough answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume favorites is an array, so you can use [**slice**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
var limit = 5;
var favorites = ['fav1', 'fav2','fav3', 'fav4','fav5', 'fav6','fav7', 'fav8'];

var x = favorites.slice(limit * -1);
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Should I write something like: 

return state.favorites.slice(limit * -1) 

If so, there is no changes, my component doesn't contain any posts now. And there are no errors

Comment: @OlgaB `return state.favorites.slice(limit * -1)` will return the last 5 items to the outer function but if you are returning the function itself further up the caller won't get the result but the function instead. That's a separate issue. I assume you intentionally return the function signature for later use. If not then you have to re-write that part.

Answer (score 1):

This question has nothing to do with vue, but you can use this to get last 5 array elements

```
getLimitFavorites(state) {
  return function(limit = 5) {
    return state.favorites.slice(-limit)
  }
},
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your solution but unfortunately it doesn't work. The component is empty now

Comment: @OlgaB This should work just fine, assuming favorites is an array and has at least 5 items in it. Using that code I got the last 5 items in the array just the same as with my approach. You might need to validate that `favorites.length > = limit`

Comment: There are no errors.

Where should I validate this?

Comment: console.log() your `favorites` or inspect your app. @Bert it's to return new copy of the array

Comment: There's no need for a new copy, slice doesn't affect the original array and returns a new array. Also not sure why there is a `limit` parameter if you don't use it.

Comment: heh.. I get splice/slice mixed sometime .. fixed!

Comment: @samayo now you have broken it as `.slice(limit)` skips the first 5 items and returns everything else instead of returning the last 5.

Comment: Yeah, fixed hopefully.